# Stored Procedure to Fetch file from Remote Machine

Tags: sql

I want to create a stored procedure that can fetch file from remote machine & Place on local server. Can anyone guide me over it please?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, I think you should clarify your question a bit with examples of what you have tried so far, and what output you are expecting. See [how to ask a question.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Also specify the environment (dbms, os.)